# variation product attribute dropdowns display the attribute slugs instead of names

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, attributes, jquery-select2, product-variations

To change the behavior of WooCommerce's variation product attribute dropdowns (when editing product) to display the attribute slugs instead of names, we need to modify the wc-enhanced-select.min.js file. This change involves editing JavaScript code. wc-enhanced-select.min.js where in terms.push must change text to : term.slug

```js
$(':input.wc-attribute-search').filter(':not(.enhanced)').each(function () {
    var select2Element = this;
    var select2_args = $.extend({
        allowClear: $(this).data('allow_clear') ? true : false,
        placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder'),
        minimumInputLength: $(this).data('minimum_input_length') !== null && $(this).data('minimum_input_length') !== undefined ? $(this).data('minimum_input_length') : '3',
        escapeMarkup: function (m) {
            return m;
        },
        ajax: {
            url: wc_enhanced_select_params.ajax_url,
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    term: params.term,
                    action: 'woocommerce_json_search_product_attributes',
                    security: wc_enhanced_select_params.search_product_attributes_nonce
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                var disabledItems = $(select2Element).data('disabled-items') || [];
                var terms = [];
                if (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (id, term) {
                        terms.push({
                            id: term.slug,
                            text: term.name,
                            disabled: disabledItems.includes(term.slug)
                        });
                    });
                }
                return {
                    results: terms
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    }, getEnhancedSelectFormatString());

    $(this).selectWoo(select2_args).addClass('enhanced');
});
```

This is a really small change and If we want to run this file from a child theme we must deregister plenty of Woocommerce scripts and then again enqueue for the right order.

Is there easier solution than this?

Any help is appreciated.